# How to use border-radius.htc with zend framework

Tags: css, zend-framework, geometry

I am building a chart drawing module in one of the projects I am working on these days. In this module, I am drawing circles by using css and in order to do that I have to use 
"-moz-border-radius: " property. It works fine in FF but not in IE. In order to make it work in IE, I have to use "border-radius.htc" as a fix to the problem. (I am using it like "behavior: url(border-radius.htc);").

Now this works fine when I am running the module as a stand alone one on my PC. But when I embed my code in Zend framework, I do not see the circles being drawn in IE (In FF, yes they show up). I tried moving border-radius.htc file to public/htc/ directory and then providing the proper url in behavior: url() property. But no difference. 
I tried to search on internet regarding this issue but could not find any useful info. I need help in order to do make it work.

Would anyone be kind enough? :)

Comment: This issue was never resolved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but can you check your server logs to see if the URL is being accessed when you open the page in IE, and whether the request is successful?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions aaz. I made all the checks necessary to see what is going on. But ZF seems so stubborn wit lots of things, although it claims its the most flexible php framework in the market. I completed my project successfully by using another work around. It was much cleaner than going for work arounds with ZF.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to make PIE work in my Zend project and found this solution:

Add PIE.htc and PIE.php in your css/ directory.

Don't define the behavior attribute in the css file but open a style tag in your index.phtml

```
<style type='text/css'>

    .pie {
        behavior: url(<?php echo $this->baseUrl("/css/PIE.php")?>); 
    }

</style>
```

And add the pie class to your element, for example

```
<div id="rounder-window" class="rounded-corners pie">
    foo
</div>
```

Of course you can define the rounded-corner class in your css file

```
.rounded-corders {

    border-radius: 10px;

    -ms-border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    -o-border-radius: 10px;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using? If it's not a windows server (iis) then you need to add the mime/type ([instructions here](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser))

Comment: It is not IIS and I set the mime/type too. Didn't work! I want to close this thread or flag it as closed (something like that), but do not know howo to do it (if I can). I've given up on ZF and not gonna recommend it for any future project in my organization. Thanks for your contribution though!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone else, trying to use Zend Framework and PIE.htc features in IE.
My steps to learn where ZF searchs for the htc file was:

1. Put the htc file into the folder "/public/htc/pie.htc"
2. Add to the *.css file the entry "behavior: url(htc/pie.htc);" (without quotes)
3. Look for a log file in your Web Server (Apache in my case) where you can see the files that are being lodaded by the Web Browser. In my case I found it in access.log.
4. I went to http://localhost/stats/machines/mem
5. I checked the access.log file and found 
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2012:12:55:05 +0100] "GET /stats/machines/htc/pie.htc HTTP/1.1" 404 6256
6. Then I modified the *.css file with: "behavior: url(../../htc/pie.htc);"
7. I went to http://localhost/stats/machines/mem
8. I checked the access.log file and found 
   127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2012:12:56:41 +0100] "GET /htc/pie.htc HTTP/1.1" 304 -

My *.css update (add ../../) my not work in all cases, but yes the process that shows how to found the solution. I hope... :)